# Dynamically display sales tax when I select a state?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a student working on an assignment. The assignment is to

- create an array that lists states
- create a parallel array that lists state taxes
- use JS to dynamically load the lists of states into the drop down menu
- create a function that will display the tax rate using parallel state array...they want us to use a loop

I am stuck on the final part where I create a function using loops that will display the sales tax. My code is below.

```
let states = ["state1", "state2", "state3", "state4"]; 
let salesTax = ["6%", "11%", "7%", "8%"];

function displayTax(){

        for(x=0; x < states.length; x++){
         document.getElementById("displayTaxPercent").innerHTML = salesTax[x];  
            
        }
    }
```

When I do this I just get 8% over and over again.

Comment: This is because you are running a loop and and when loop finishes it will have last value and that is 8%, where are you from getting selected state value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting value as **8%** is because you are not giving the selected value and code is simply iterating through all values and hence it will always show last value.
Here is simple example

```js
let states = ["state1", "state2", "state3", "state4"]; 
let salesTax = ["6%", "11%", "7%", "8%"];

function displayTax(state){

console.log(state + " : " + salesTax[states.indexOf(state)])
//document.getElementById("displayTaxPercent").innerHTML = salesTax[states.indexOf(state)];  
    }   
 
 displayTax("state1");
 displayTax("state3");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const stateSelect = document.querySelector("#stateSelect");

let states = ["state1", "state2", "state3", "state4"];
let salesTax = ["6%", "11%", "7%", "8%"];

stateSelect.append(
  ...states.map((state, stateI) => {
    const optionEl = document.createElement("option");

    optionEl.value = stateI;
    optionEl.innerText = state;

    return optionEl;
  })
);

const display = () => {
  document.querySelector("#results").innerText =
    "Sales tax in " +
    states[stateSelect.value] +
    " is " +
    salesTax[stateSelect.value];
};

stateSelect.addEventListener("change", display);

display();
```

```html
<select id="stateSelect">
</select>

<p id="results"></p>
```